# How to convert the data formats of the trained model from "NCHW" to "NHWC" with TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have my own `pytorch, onnx, tf1.x(frozen_graph.pb), and tf2.x(saved_model.pb)` models.

Each of those model outputs is exactly same as I expected.

> The original model is PyTorch model, but I converted it into the following sequences to run the model on my objective embedded platform:

`PyTorch -> onnx -> tf2.x saved_model.pb -> tf1.x frozen_graph.pb`

The problem is that. The objective embedded platform only supports data in **NHWC** format. But my whole models have **NCHW** format.

So the question is, is there any way to convert the data formats of the trained model from **NCHW** to **NHWC** using `tf1.x` or `tf2.x`?

Please advice.